# load the css from tiles definition xml

Tags: java

```
How can i load the css from tiles definition file in springs?

My JSP:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%-- <tiles:importAttribute name="cssList" /> --%>
<tiles:useAttribute id = "stylesList" name="styles" classname="java.util.List"/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<%-- <link href="<c:url value="/styles/cssreset-min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> --%>
<%-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<tiles:getAsString name="cssList"/>"/> --%>
    <%-- <link href="<c:url value="cssList"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> --%>

      <c:forEach var="eachStyle" items="${styles}">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:out value='${eachStyle}'/>"    />
      </c:forEach> 
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
```

This is my tiles xml file?

```
<definition name="template-main" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/main.jsp">
       <!--  <put-attribute name="cssList" value="/resources/styles/cssreset-min.css" type="string"/> -->
        <put-attribute name="banner-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sections/banner.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="title-content" value="Pet Type" />
        <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sections/footer.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="styles">
          <add-list-attribute>
             <add-attribute value="/resources/styles/cssreset-min.css"></add-attribute>
          </add-list-attribute>
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
```

I just want to load the css from tiles definition xml file. How can i do this?
Can anyone please help . I am new to this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake on the var id to retrieve the items list (at the c:forEach tag).

You are referencing the name (used by [tiles:useAttribute](http://tiles.apache.org/2.0/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/useAttribute.html)) to retrieve the Tiles value, and not the id (which is the key to find the list retrieved at the JSP, in short, the defined variable name).

Your code should look like this:

```
  <c:forEach var="eachStyle" items="stylesList">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:out value='${eachStyle}'/>"    />
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks tomas .. I am able to get the url from the tiles definition file but it looks like this [styles/styles.css] enclosed within square brackets because of which its not able to  load the css. Is there any problem with this   <put-list-attribute name="styles">
          <add-list-attribute>
             <add-attribute value="/resources/styles/cssreset-min.css"></add-attribute>
          </add-list-attribute>
        </put-list-attribute>

Comment: @user1122897 Try changing the `<c:out />` by `<tiles:insertAttribute value="${eachStyle}" />`

Comment: I tried that too thomas but didnt work. I need to get the elements of the list in my jsp ie i need to read the elemnts of the list one by one. <c:forEach var="eachStyle" items="${styles}" > 
          <c:url var="eachStyleTemp" value="${eachStyle}" />
               <a href="${eachStyle}">CSS </a>
              
       <c:out value="${eachStyle}"/>  . My list is somewhat like this[styles/sample.css,styles/sample2.css,styles/sample3.css,]